# Inner Join Giving a blank page

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo

This is my first attempt at Using Inner Joins as i have always been using SELECTS till now.
I am trying to combine 2 tables together using INNER JOIN but am having no luck thus far.

My INNER JOIN Query:

```
$viewsubcat=$cxn->prepare("SELECT `testdb`.`itemcat`.`CatID`,`testdb`.`itemcat`.`ItemCat`,`testdb`.`itemsubcat`.`ItemSubCat` 
    FROM `testdb`.`itemcat` 
    INNER JOIN `testdb`.`itemsubcat` 
    ON `testdb`.`itemcat`.`CatID`=`testdb`.`itemsubcat`.`ItemCat`");
    $viewsubcat->execute();
    while($getsubcat=$viewsubcat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $cat=$getsubcat["`testdb`.`itemcat`.ItemCat`"];
        $subcat=$getsubcat["`testdb`.`itemsubcat`.`ItemSubCat`"];
        echo"$cat";
        echo"$subcat";
    }
```

I am getting a blank screen, and NO error messages from the error logs.I've been trying for nearly 2 hours now and still can't get it to work.

My Tables:

```
+----------------------------------+
| CatID | BusinessID |    ItemCat  |
------------------------------------
|   1   |      1     |   Computers |
------------------------------------
|   2   |      1     |    Games    |
------------------------------------


+-----------------------------------------------+
| SubCatID | BusinessID | ItemCat | ItemSubCat  |
-------------------------------------------------
|     4    |     1      |    1    |  NoteBooks  |
-------------------------------------------------
|     5    |     1      |    1    |  Tablets    |
-------------------------------------------------
```

EDIT:Results with MYSQL(Without PHP)

CatID     ItemCat      ItemSubCat

```
1        Computers    NoteBooks

1        Computers    Tablets
```

Would REALLY appreciate any help i can get

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe there are no results to return. The inner join checks for pairs of results in which the condition is true. Maybe it is not the case.

Comment: What do you get if you run that query directly in MySQL (without using PHP)?

Comment: @Mihai If i remove $link, all i get is a screen with the words connected successfully. The results of the query do not show up =X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$cat=$getsubcat["ItemCat"];
$subcat=$getsubcat["ItemSubCat"];
```

Comment: It works!!! Just a question though, I thought that an inner join was suppose to join 2 tables together and display it.However, by echoing out $cat and $subcat, am i not simply echoing fields that were selected.? If that's the case, wouldn't i be better off using 2 SELECT statements and then echoing them in a table?

Comment: In that Join just created those fields dont exist anymore,they are just for Mysql,now you have an array( id => 1 ItemCat => blah ItemSubCat => blah) and so on for each row.